# Java jface calling browser from an relative location

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have encountered a small problem that I need some help on. The issue is that I wish to call a browser window which calls a html page. The html file opens in 3 different browsers so the code for that should be correct. The actual problem is that it brings up a page can't be displayed error message

Here is the code that gets the location

```
    package org.error;

    public class BrowserLocation {

        private String test1 = "org\\error\\PatientNumberError.html";

        public BrowserLocation() {
        }

        public String patientNumberAddress() {
            return test1;
        }
    }
```

and here is the code that creates the browser component and calls the location of the html file.

```
    Browser browser = new Browser(container, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
    browser.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    browser.setUrl(browserLocation.patientNumberAddress());
    browser.setBounds(25, 25, 315, 180);
```

Would it be possible to find the error of my ways?

Comment: what happens exactly?

Comment: The actual problem is that it brings up a page can't be displayed error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setUrl` require a `URL` so you need something like:

```
browser.setUrl(new File(path).toURI().toURL().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not getting back to you earlier.
Someone that I know who is a senior Java programmer told me the problem that I was having was a case of **absolute address** versus **relative address**.

The reason for this is that if I was reading and writing to a file, then I would be able to use a relative address. However If I'm interacting with a server which is the case here as eventually It could go on-line (If I had the money) it would need to be an absolute address.

As I am still learning Java programming this was a very specific and important lesson to learn. I hope this would help anybody else who has had this issue.